# Динамическое изменение адреса загрузки

Tags: jquery, javascript

```
<select id="selectGallery">
  <option value="/gallery/solntse/">Солнце</option>
  <option value="/gallery/gory/">Горы</option>
  <option value="/gallery/more/">Море</option>
</select>
```

Загрузка картинок

```
function createUploader(){
    var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
        element: document.getElementById('fileupload'),
        action: '/wp-content/themes/ccl/upload.php',
        params: {paths: $('#selectGallery option:selected').val()},
        multiple: true,
        debug: true,
        onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){
            alert(responseJSON.filenames);
        },
        allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif']
    });           
}
```

Есть селект - хочу при отправке на сервер менять адрес загружения картинки,  для этого решил в params передавать адрес, куда загружать картинку. Но проблема в том, что адрес в paths прописывается только 1 раз при загрузке плагина... как можно поменять данные params динамически?

Comment: Решил вопрос тем что каждый раз при изменении перезаписываю функцию... думаю не сильно правильно но что поделать :(

$('#selectGallery').change(function(){ createUploader(); })

Comment: а может имеет смысл вызывать эту функцию только когда посылают форму?

Comment: Да собственно нет... Тут же кнопка выбора картинко работает после запуска... Он вешается на определённый элемент который становтся кнопкой обзор..

element: document.getElementById('fileupload')

ну по крайней мере я пока не придумал как :)